# Select the number of rows instead of the content in it

Tags: mysql, select

Once, I used this query to select the number of items in order to create a list of pages:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM lists WHERE online = 1
```

But now it has become difficult, since there are more conditions. Now I need to know the number of lists that are online which have subtitles which have list items in it.

I tried the following, but it gives multiple rows instead of one number:

```
SELECT COUNT(lists.id)
FROM lists
INNER JOIN subtitles ON subtitles.list_id = lists.id
INNER JOIN listitems ON listitems.subtitle_id = subtitles.id
WHERE lists.online = 1
GROUP BY lists.id
```

Of course I know that it's possible to calculate the number of lists with PHP, but it would be a lot faster to select the number of lists with MySQL only.

So, is there any way to select the number of rows without getting the actual content of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted to achieve :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(lists.id))
FROM lists
INNER JOIN subtitles ON subtitles.list_id = lists.id
INNER JOIN listitems ON listitems.subtitle_id = subtitles.id
WHERE lists.online = 1
```

Instead of grouping the lists, you can simply take the count of distinct within the join. If the count is all you want to get anyway, it's even easier.

Comment: Thank you, that's it :]. I tried `DISTINCT COUNT(lists.id)` but I didn't know it was possible to use it inside `COUNT()`